# Web Essentials LESS compile

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

Using Web Essentials for VS2013 with VS2013. Have installed bootstrap LESS files. Opening bootstrap.less shows preview of compiled css and output log reports successfull compile but where are the css files? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In VS, if you go to Tools > Options > Web Essentials > LESS > Custom Output Directory, it says: "On default compiled css files will be placed in the same folder and nested under the original file". So when Content\bootstrap\bootstrap.less gets compiled to css, you can find the css file under Content\bootstrap\bootstrap.css.

Not sure if it's a good practice to use the bootstrap.css in that manner though.